# Loop skips over getchar in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I am working on a simple program in C that asks the user to give an input in a loop until they enter the letter `Q` when prompted. When I run the program however, it immediately skips the prompt to enter a character and asks the user to enter another input. Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Here is my code:

```
    while (exit != 'q' && exit != 'Q') {
        printf("Please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", assignmentNumber);
        scanf("%lf", &gradeInput);

        printf("Press q to quit, press any other character to continue: ");
        exit = getchar();
    }
```

I tried changing the `getchar` to `scanf(%c%*c)` like I saw someone suggest under a post with a similar problem. It did make it so the prompt to enter a character actually worked, but the loop no longer ended when `Q` is entered.

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` and `getchar()`. Preferably use exclusively `fgets()` for **ALL** user input (for the grade, for the quit character, ...). `scanf()` was not designed for user input; `getchar()` alone can be a PITA; `fgets()` works like `getchar()` on steroids.

Comment: A duplicate of [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `getchar()` reads the next character from the input line after the floating point number typed by the user. This could be anything, but in most cases, this character will be the newline stored into the input stream when the user hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You should modify your program to:

- read input one line at a time
- check for end of file
- check for success in the conversion of the user input as a number

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double gradeInput;
    int assignmentNumber = 1;

    for (;;) {
        char input[128];
        printf("Please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", assignmentNumber);
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            /* end of file */
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(input, "%lf", &gradeInput) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input: %s\n", input);
            continue;
        }
        /* handle the grade */
        // [...]
        assignmentNumber++;

        printf("Press q to quit, press any other character to continue: ");
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            /* end of file */
            break;
        }
        if (input[0] == 'q' || input[0] == 'Q')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This call of `getchar`

```
exit = getchar ();
```

can read new line character `'\n'`.

Instead change the statement like

```
scanf( " %c", &exit );
        ^^^
```

provided that `exit` has the type `char`.

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allowes to skip white space characters.

Also it would be better to change the while loop to do-while loop like

```
do 
{
    printf("Please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", assignmentNumber);
    scanf("%lf", &gradeInput);

    printf("Press q to quit, press any other character to continue: ");
    scanf( " %c", &exit );
} while ( exit != 'q' && exit != 'Q' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you're facing is related to the way the newline character left in the input buffer after reading a double (with `scanf("%lf", &gradeInput)`) is affecting the behaviour of `getchar()`. The `getchar()` function reads the next character from the input buffer, which includes any leftover newline characters.

To fix this issue, you can clear the input buffer after reading the grade by consuming the newline character. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char exit = ' ';
    double gradeInput;
    int assignmentNumber = 1;

    do {
        printf("Please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", assignmentNumber);

        if (scanf("%lf", &gradeInput) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear the input buffer
            continue;
        }

        while ((exit = getchar()) != '\n' && exit != EOF); // Clear the input buffer

        printf("Press q to quit, press any other character to continue: ");
        exit = getchar();
        while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear the input buffer

        assignmentNumber++;
    } while (exit != 'q' && exit != 'Q');

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, we use a while loop to clear the input buffer by reading characters until a newline character is encountered. This ensures that any leftover characters, including the newline character, are removed from the input buffer before attempting to read the exit character. This should fix the issue and allow your loop to end when `Q` or `q` is entered.

Comment: @chqrlie I fixed it

Comment: Jibel, I think you misunderstood what @chqrlie said. You still have the potentially infinite loop `while (getchar() != '\n');` in there.

Comment: What other commenters are saying is that you need to check for `EOF`, too, since `getchar()` might return this for a number of reasons. Something like: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { continue; }` is traditional.

Comment: @adabsurdum Did it fixed in the new edit?

Comment: Using different input methods and then applying kludges to get round their different behaviour is a hiding to nowhere. Use one input method, preferbly `fgets()`.

Comment: Jibel -- not quite. You need to check for `EOF` in _all_ of the loops that clear the input stream, and it is probably a bad idea to use `exit` in those loops. Consider: a user selects `'q'` to quit, setting `exit` to `'q'`, then the loop that clears the input stream writes over `exit` with characters from the input stream. After that, the code checks to see if the user entered `'q'` or `'Q'` and probably gets the wrong idea!

Comment: You have two more potential infinite loops with `while (getchar() != '\n')`. Also `exit` should have type `int`, not `char`.  You should test for `EOF` in the `while` clause of the `do` / `while` loop.  Using a `for(;;)` loop with explicit tests and `break` statements would be more readable and allow for better consistency.